# A new Spring ServletDispatcher/ HandlerMapping redirect request based on domain name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-dispatching

I'm using Spring + Gradle + PostgreSQL, and I want to write a new Spring ServletDispatcher or HandlerMapping (I don't know which one is the best choice).

The requirement is: Redirect the HTTP request to different controller according to it's sub domain name.

For example:

HTTP request to:
aaa.domain.com will be redirect to => websites/aaa/
bbb.domain.com => websites/bbb/

How could I write it?

My Gradle dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

Thanks very much!

## First update

I researched Spring a little deeper. And now I think a new HandlerMapping might be a better choice. So I want to rewrite the *DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping* .

It's a class of package *spring-webmvc* , and defined in *DispatcherServlet.properties* as follows:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping=org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,\
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
```

I can't change the *DispatcherServlet.properties* directly. So if I want to replace the class with my class, how could I do that?

I used a lot of spring-boot-starter instead of XML to define my project.

I tried to define the *org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping* in *application.properties* but failed.

Comment: Try writing some code then post it, so we can help you. We can't produce code for you

Comment: You can check reverse proxying  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). It can distribute the request to spring request handlers based on the domains.

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept the request and get the subdomain and then forward it to your desired path.

You can either implement a `HandlerInterceptor` or extend `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` for this purpose. Here is an example that gets the subdomain and forwards:

```
@Component
public class DomainHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                             HttpServletResponse response, Object o) throws Exception {
        String subDomain = request.getServerName().split("\\.")[0];
        if (request.getAttribute("domainHandled") != null) {
            request.setAttribute("domainHandled", true);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/websites/" + subDomain)
                    .forward(request, response);
            System.out.println(request.getRequestURL().toString());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Add the `DomainInterceptor` to the interceptor registry:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired 
    HandlerInterceptor domainHandlerInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(domainHandlerInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should put it into HandlerExecutionChain then, I think. But I didn't find a way to disable the initialize of the bean HandlerInterceptorAdapter and replace it with DomainHandlerInterceptor.

Comment: You don't need to disable anything. Just add the `DomainHandlerInterceptor` to your `InterceptorRegistry`. See the edited answer

Comment: I updated the question, could you please help me a little further?